# How to publish a message to a redis channel using lumen broadcast?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, lumen

I have an event called 'Event1' and an event listener 'Event1Listener' for the event in my lumen application. I need to publish a custom message to a redis channel called 'channel1' when event1 is fired. How can I do this?

**Event1.php**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Events;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
    class Event1 extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        /**
        * Create a new event instance.
        * @return void
        */
        public function __construct() {        
        }
        /**
        * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
        *
        * @return array
        */
        public function broadcastOn() {
            return ['channel1'];
        }
    }
?>
```

**Event1Listener.php**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Listeners;

    use App\Events\Event1;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

    class Event1Listener  {
        /**
        * Create the event listener.
        *
        * @return void
        */
        public function __construct(){
        }
        /**
        * Handle the event.
        *
        * @param  Event1  $event
        * @return void
        */
        public function handle(Event1 $event) {
            echo "What should I add here?";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You have configured `Redis` If not check out the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redis) and [lumen documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache)

To publish message to the channel you could use the command

```
public function handle(Event1 $event) {
    Redis::publish('channel1', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
}
```

Comment: Getting an error when `Redis::publish()` is called. I have `"illuminate/redis": "~5.1"` and `"predis/predis":"~1.0"` in my composer.json and also called `Use Redis` in the listener file. Vendor folder contains illuminate/redis directory and also registered Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider in my bootstrap/app.php file.

Comment: Please share your `app.php` file and have you tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: `$app->configure('broadcasting');
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);  
$app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);`

Comment: @LJP : Check out this issue [thread](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/414) and have you configured your redis in `config/database.php` ?